# Dataflow: Hot keys in a cross join

Tags: bigdata, google-cloud-dataflow, distributed-computing, apache-beam, cross-join

I am using Google dataflow+ Scio to do a cross join of a dataset with itself to find out the topK most similar ones by doing cosine similarity. The data set has around 200k records and total size of the dataset is ~300MB.

I am joining the dataset with itself by passing it as a side input by setting the workerCacheMB to 500MB.

The dataset is a tuple and it looks like this: (String,Set(Integer)). The first element in the tuple is the URI and the next element is a set of entity indexes.

Most records in the dataset have under 500 entity indexes. However, there are about 7000 records which have over 10k entities and the maximum one has 171k entities.

I have some hot keys and hence the worker utitlization looks like this:
[image]

After it scaled up to 80 nodes and then scaled down to 1 node, it had already processed about 90% of the records. I assume, the hot keys have got stuck in the last one node and it took the rest of the time to process all the hotkeys.

I tried the `--experiments=shuffle_mode=service` option. Though it gave an improvement, the problem persists. I was thinking about ways to use the sharded HotKey join mentioned [here](https://labs.spotify.com/2014/12/19/torching-our-reducers-taught-us-this-essential-lesson/), how ever since I need to find similarity I don't think I can afford to split the hot entities and rejoin them.

I was wondering if there is a way to solve it or if I basically have to live with this.
Obviously, this is a crude way to find sims. However, I am interested in finding solution to the Data engineering part of the problem, while letting ML engineers iterate on the Sim finding algorithms.

The stripped down version of the code looks as follows:

```
private def findSimilarities(e1: Set[Integer], e2: Set[Integer]): Float = {
    val common = e1.intersect(e2)
    val cosine = (common.size.toFloat) / (e1.size + e2.size).toFloat
    cosine
  }

val topN = sortedReverseTake[ElementSims](250)(by(_.getScore))

elements
      .withSideInputs(elementsSI)
      .flatMap { case (e1, si) =>
        val fromUri = e1._1.toString
        val fromEntities = e1._2
        val sideInput: List[(String, Set[Integer])] = si(elementsSI)
        val sims: List[ElementSims] = findSimilarities(fromUri,fromEntities,
          sideInput)
        topN(sims)
      }
      .toSCollection
      .saveAsAvroFile(outputGCS)
```

Comment: by saying topK, these K elements make a cluster, right? meaning the overall cosine-similarity within this cluster is maximal, which means, if you replace any one out of these K elements, we end up having less overall consine-similarity.

Comment: The 500MB cache should be enough to keep everything in memory, but just in case could you try a couple of experiments?

Quick test : Add a larger cache ( In batch mode you would not see OOM if cache was too small as the cache will make use of gcs when needed, but this is not optimal, especially if you are doing lots of lookups, which if I have understood your use case you are)

Longer Test: Can you switch to using CoGroupByKey rather than a side input?

Comment: @RezaRokni I tried upping the cache(to 1000MB) and machine type. But no luck. I can try the CoGroupByKey approach. I resisted myself from not doing that thinking, I might have to generate the cross products by hand which might make it a really expensive operation. Please let me know if that is not right.

Comment: @O-OF-N how's it going? Any luck? : )

Comment: @RezaRokni When I try to co-group by key, my job takes 3.5 hours instead of 4. But all the 200 workers are alive all the time which significantly increases the cost for half hour gain.  So not much luck.